# ASP.NET controller does not receiving data from Ajax POST call

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I've been to basically all questions there were but seems I'm missing something pretty basic.

I have a simple class:

```
public class Recebe
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

A controller POST action:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult ToggleLikeClicked(Recebe recebe)
{
    return Json("Retorno");
}
```

And an Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: '/StartUps/ToggleLikeClicked',
     contentType: 'application/json',
     dataType: 'json',
     data: JSON.stringify({
          'Name': 'Sergio',
           'Email': 'sergio@difiore.com.br'
     }),
     beforeSend: function () {
        console.log('Before send');
     },
     success: function (response) {
        console.log('success');
        console.log(response);
      },
      complete: function () {
         console.log('completed');
      },
      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          console.log('Status: ' + jqXHR.status + '; Error: ' + jqXHR.responseText);
      },
  });
```

From the browser console, I know the whole thing is executed, yet when debugging the "receive" is null.

What's wrong?

Comment: I suspect the json you are creating is not the same 'shape' as `Recebe`.

Comment: Just sent a string value first and check its hitting ToggleLikeClicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try editing the JSON you are sending to:

```
{
    'name': 'Sergio',
    'email': 'sergio@difiore.com.br'
}
```

You can also try adding the [FromBody] attribute to the parameter in the controller:

```
public IActionResult ToggleLikeClicked([FromBody] Recebe recebe)
```

Comment: Just for the record, it works with the [FromBody] and have to keep the JSON.stringify.